How can I set the hint text if some value is entered into it? (Java,Andorid Studio)
I have 14 EditTexts in the XML, how do I retrieve the hint from the text where some value is entered and pass that hint from the text and set it in a TextView?
I've been trying to solve that problem for a few days and find solutions, but I haven't succeeded. Does anyone have an idea how I could solve it.
Here is Result.java



 String sunflowerOil = getIntent().getStringExtra("sunflowerOil");
    String sweetAlmondOil = getIntent().getStringExtra("sweetAlmondOil");


    TextView textView19 = findViewById(R.id.textView19);
    TextView textView20 = findViewById(R.id.textView20);

    TextView textView22 = findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    TextView textView23 = findViewById(R.id.textView23);

    textView22.setText(arganOil.isEmpty() ? hintEditText1 : arganOil.isEmpty() ? hintEditText1 : "Hint 1");
    textView23.setText(neemOil.isEmpty() ? hintEditText2 : neemOil.isEmpty() ? hintEditText2 : "Hint 2");

Here is Ingredients.java:
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:hint="Argan Oil"
    android:ems="4"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

     String arganOil = editText1.getText().toString();
            String neemOil = editText2.getText().toString();

            String hintEditText1 = editText1.getHint().toString();
            String hintEditText2 = editText2.getHint().toString();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Ingredients.this, Result.class);
            intent.putExtra("arganOil", arganOil);
            intent.putExtra("neemOil", neemOil);


Have you tried using addTextChangedListener on those edit text? Can you please show a [mcve] of your code?

I hope this is enough code

You seem to understand how to use getHint and setText, so I'm not sure I understand the question. But if you want to wait for actual user input in an EditText, you'll need to have some addTextChangedListener on each EditText

Here's a better explanation: I have 14 EditText fields, and let's say the user enters some value in one of those fields. I want to retrieve the hint text from the EditText where a value is entered and set it in a TextView. I hope u understand now. Thank you.

You can get the value that is entered, as it is entered, or just the hint, within editText1.addTextChangedListener, for example.
